# How does the following r.p. notation read in plain English?

Tags: notation, random-variables

See [this link](https://www.math.ust.hk/~maykwok/courses/ma246/04_05/04MA246L4A.pdf) at Page-$07$.

> If the stochastic process is discrete-valued, then a collection of probability mass
>   functions can be used to specify the stochastic process:
>
> $$P_{X_1···X_k}(x_1, x_2, · · · , x_k) = P(X_1 = x_1, X_2 = x_2, ··· , X_k = x_k)$$

How does the above r.p. notation read in plain English?

As far as I can tell:

> **Probability** of the Random Process $X(k, \zeta)$ is equal to the **joint probability** of the random variables $X_1, X_2, ... , X_k$.
>
> **Note.** $\zeta$ is the sample space.

But, why is it written as $P(X_1 = x_1, X_2 = x_2, ··· , X_k = x_k)$?

It seems that $X_1$ can't take the value $x_2$? Why?

Aren't $x_1$ and $x_2$ both members of sample space $\zeta$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lower-case $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k$ are dummy variables. They represent generic values for the corresponding random variables $X_1, X_2,\ldots, X_k$, the same way that $x$ and $y$ are generic variables in the joint density $f(x,y)$ of a bivariate pair $(X,Y)$. The dummy variables have different subscripts so we can keep straight which dummy variable is associated with which random variable.

In equations involving $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k$, unless explicitly restricted, these variables are understood to take any legal value: For example, in the equation (which is actually defining the LHS)
$$
P_{X_1···X_k}(x_1, x_2, · · · , x_k) = P(X_1 = x_1, X_2 = x_2, ··· , X_k = x_k)
$$
you should read the implicit "for all possible values of $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k$".

Comment: Are rest of my conceptions correct?

Comment: @yahoo.com Yes, the probability mass function $P_{X_1···X_k}(x_1, x_2, · · · , x_k)$ is shorthand for the joint probability $P(X_1 = x_1, X_2 = x_2, ··· , X_k = x_k)$. The assertion is that to define the random process, it is enough to specify the collection of p.m.f.'s as $k$ ranges over all positive integers.